# What is difference between StackExchange.Redis.StrongName.Core and StackExchange.Redis.StrongName

Tags: .net, .net-core, redis, package, nuget

What is difference between *StackExchange.Redis.StrongName.Core* and *StackExchange.Redis.StrongName* nuget packages?

*StackExchange.Redis.StrongName.Core*: version 1.2.6, published 2017, 16.3M downloads
*StackExchange.Redis.StrongName*:      version 1.1.605, published 2016, 56.1M downloads

I cannot find better descritpion for *StackExchange.Redis.StrongName.Core* than in Nuget. They both seems to be the same. Both are compatible from net standard 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nuget page for `StackExchange.Redis.StrongName.Core` suggests that it was a separate package developed when .NET Core was new. https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis.StrongName.Core/

> Alpha for .NET Core RTM; if you aren't doing .NET Core, you probably don't want this

So if you're working on a .NET Core project now, you will most likely want the `StackExchange.Redis.StrongName` package which seems to be the 'productionised' version and supports .NET Core.